# How to set shipping tax on rate

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping, tax

I have a method with create a shipping rate, but I need to add shipping tax on this specific rate, how can i do this?
My class:

```
$method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();
$method->setCarrier($this->_code);
$method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData("title"));
$method->setMethod("ddr");
$method->setMethodTitle($response[0]['messages']['result']['service'] . " - " . " Delivery time " . $response[0]['messages']['result']['totalTransitDays'] . " day(s)");
$shippingCost = (float)$response[0]['messages']['result']['costFreight'];
$method->setPrice($shippingCost);
$method->setCost($shippingCost);

$result->append($method);
```

i have already tried this, but didn't works:

```
$method->setBaseShippingTaxAmount(8);
$method->setTaxAmount(8);
```

**

### I need that if the customer chooses my specific rate, the tax that I choose appears. in the summary.

**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

please chnage setting from admin instead of code.(Tax Class for Shipping = Taxable Goods)

[image]

mark solution if right for you.

Comment: Ok, but how can i add tax in my shipping rate?

Comment: add shipping rate including tax "$method->setPrice($shippingCost);"

Comment: But that way the tax will not be highlighted, I edited my question to better exemplify.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my method. I have uploaded my code to pastebin so you can easily read it: https://pastebin.com/5AgsE5eY